# Standard library identifiers conflict with user identifiers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am attempting to compile/link my file named test.cpp from the command line using VS2017 on a 64-bit Win10 system.  I use these two commands:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
cl test.cpp
```

and I get the following results:

```
C:\temp\tests>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.4.5
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

C:\temp\tests>cl test.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
test.cpp(2): error C2365: 'y1': redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(984): note: see declaration of 'y1'
test.cpp(5): error C2659: '=': function as left operand
```

My file contains the following code:

```
#include <new>
static int *y1;
int main()
{
   y1 = new (std::nothrow) int;
}
```

While I understand why this is happening and any number of kluges that will fix it, it seems to me that the actual defect is in the Microsoft corecrt_math.h header file.  When I look there I see several more identifiers (j0, jn, jn, etc.) that could just as easily be legitimately chosen by an unsuspecting programmer, only to end up with the same problem.  I was under the impression that there was a "gentlemen's agreement" that exposed undocumented identifiers in library code would start or end with an underbar and user code would not, just to avoid this type of problem.

Comment: Is there a question hidden in there somewhere

Comment: Bessel functions etc. were introduced in C++17. They should only be available via `<cmath>`, not via `<math.h>`. Of course, considering history, that was not such a realistic requirement, it was IMHO stupid. **OH**. Microsoft introduced some of these with simpler names at least back [in VS 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7zkk1bz.aspx). Still from the docs it looks like they have leading underscore?

Comment: I've **reproduced** the problem with Visual C++ 2017.

Comment: `y1` is also a POSIX.1-2001 function specified to be in `<math.h>`. But it's interesting it would end up indirectly included from `<new>`.

Comment: Seems like a bug report, not a question. Microsoft should be informed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This build command works for me:

```
cl foo.cpp /Feb /D _CRT_DECLARE_NONSTDC_NAMES=0
```

Comment: That's a nice Nice find.

Comment: [Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/161276/view.html) is an explanation from Steve Wishnousky at MSFT. TLDR it's compliant because the function name is reserved by POSIX. It may be better to just rename on your end.

Comment: Great answer.  When I examined the MSFT file a little closer I noticed that macro and was about to try disabling it just to see what would happen, then I saw this posting.  My only concern is if disabling it might break something in some existing or future non-POSIX code.

Comment: @BenevolentDeity: I wasn't aware of it until this question. But just searching the VC++ include files shows that it controls inclusion of a great many no-leading-underscore macros and functions. I'll be defining it as 0 from now on.